# How do I import the "Organization ID (Optional)" in Service Desk?

Tags: csv, import

I am trying to import users into the Service Desk and I'm going to do it with the csv import.

I have used the example file as a template and everything goes fine but not the "Organization ID (Optional)".

In the file i put the name of the organization inside "", like this.

```
Email,Name,Phone,Notes,Avdelning,"Organization ID (Optional)"
test@test.xxx,Test Testsson,,,IT Department,"Company XYZ"
```

Is the ID something else? Because I can't find any ID on the Organizations just name.

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question? Please show us what you tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

The organization ID is an optional value that you can leave as blank. It might be an identifier as to which company would the user belong to or a simple Employee ID. However, I tried uploading a couple of sample users with and without a value on Organizational ID and I was able to upload them.

Please see the documentation help guide for additional information. https://help.comodo.com/topic-289-1-629-7979-Managing-Users.html#add_user